# Checking for duplicate nested arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that will be populated with information each time the user clicks a button.  The information being pushed to this array is within an array itself.  so something along the lines of this:

```
var parentArray = [];
var childArray = ["Info1", "Info2", 500];

$("#button").on("click", function(){
    parentArray.push(childArray);
})
```

Each time the user clicks the button, the `childArray` will have different information based on a different user input.  For example, the user clicks on one point on a map, the `childArray` takes certain information into it.  The user clicks on a different point on the map and the `childArray` takes certain information into it.  Each time the `childArray` will be different or the same.  the user then clicks the button and the information in the `childArray` is pushed to the `parentArray`.

My issue is, I want to get rid of duplicate `childArrays` from within the `parentArray`.  So, say one `childArray` looks like this:

`["Info1", "Info2", 25]`

Another child array looks like this:
`["Info1", "Info2", 50]`

And another looks like this:
`["Info1", "Info2", 25]`

I want to find if two `childArrays` are the same, the first and third arrays, and if they are, remove all but one similar array so in the end, instead of looking like this:

`[["Info1", "Info2", 25], ["Info1", "Info2", 50], ["Info1", "Info2", 25]]`

my `parentArray` would look like this:

`[["Info1", "Info2", 25], ["Info1", "Info2", 50]]`

Is it possible to achieve this?  If so, how would I go about doing it?

I hope this made sense.

Comment: Yes it's possible, what have you tried?

Comment: you could find an answer here ,in case   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680430/get-unique-results-from-json-array-using-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518651/elminating-duplicates-in-a-json-object

Comment: Here how to check if arrays match with jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773069/using-jquery-to-compare-two-arrays-of-javascript-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and `thisArg` parameter

```js
var ar = [["Info1", "Info2", 25], ["Info1", "Info2", 50], ["Info1", "Info2", 25]];
var result = ar.filter(function(e) {
  if(!this[e.join('|')]) {
    this[e.join('|')] = true;
    return e;
  }
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry, I saw what I did wrong in regards to my first comment.  Can you explain why you have a separate set of curly brackets and why it actually makes it work?

Comment: That is object as `thisArg` parameter or `this` in function.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So it just creates an empty object when the filter method completes?

Comment: Not really, it adds your element (as string) - `this[e.join()]` as `this` object key and set it to true or whatever if there isn't property with same key already in `this` object and returns it. If there was same object in array already or same key of `this` filter doesn't return it. https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1081/

Comment: You are doing this just check is `this` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1083/